# Modal dentro de un foreach - Laravel - Blade

Tags: laravel, blade

Un Saludo,

Enfocándonos en el tag de **edición:**

Actualmente estoy intentado hacer un update desde una tabla en **HTML** en la que tengo varios registros, activando un Modal, sin tener que ir a otra pantalla, ya que son solamente dos campos por registro que necesito actualizar, pero el problema que tengo es que a pesar de que puedo pasar el id del registro que deseo actualizar a la etiqueta `<a href="{{$list->id_list}}"></a>` no puedo pasarlo al modal para actualizar exactamente el registro que deseo, como he intentado mostrarlo en el **placeholder**. Sin importar que registro desee actualizar solo me toma el id del último registro que en este caso es el **35**.

Lo que deseo hacer es poder pasar al modal el id del registro que necesito actualizar.

```html
<tbody>
  @foreach ($lists as $list)
  <tr>
    <td>{{$list->id_list}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->list_name}}</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>{{$list->created_at}}</td>
    <td>{{$list->updated_at}}</td>
    <td>
      <a href="{{url('/sus_list/' . $list->id_list)}}" title="Upload E-mails"><i
                                                    class="material-icons">
                                                    backup
                                                </i></a>
      <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalEdit" href="{{$list->id_list}}"><i
                                                    class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
      <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelEdit" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
          <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
              <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabelEdit">Create Subscribers List</h5>
              <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                                                                <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                                                            </button>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
              <form method="POST" action="/sus_list" id="formModalValidate">
                @csrf
                <input type="hidden" name="lista_id" value="{{$list->id_list}}">
                <div class="input-field col s12">
                  <label for="list_name" class="col-form-label">List Name:</label>
                  <input type="text" class="form-control" name="list_name" id="recipient-name" minlength="4" required placeholder="{{$list->id_list}}">
                </div>
                <div class="col s12">
                  <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label"></label>
                  <select name="list_type" id="" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-white" title="" required>
                    <option value="" disabled selected>Type List</option>
                    <option value="1">Email Makerting</option>
                  </select>
                </div>
                <br>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
                </div>
              </form>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
    </td>
  </tr>
  @endforeach
</tbody>
```

**Imagen de la vista:**
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 1):

El problema lo terminé resolviendo sacando el Modal del foreach y con una funcion en JS tomaba el id y luego lo replicaba al modal, a continuación el código:

JavaScript:

```html
 function capturar(e)
 {
    let value = e; 
    document.getElementById("idListJs").value=value;
    console.log(value)
 }
```

**Blade:**

```html
<table class="table">
  <thead class=" text-primary">
    <th>ID</th>
    <th>List Name </th>
    <th>Total Suscribers</th>
    <th>Created Date</th>
    <th> Updated Date</th>
    <th>Options</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    @foreach ($lists as $key=> $list)
    <tr>
      <td>{{$list->id_list}}</td>
      <td>{{$list->list_name}}</td>
      <td>0</td>
      <td>{{$list->created_at}}</td>
      <td> {{$list->updated_at}}</td>
      <td>
        <a href="{{url('/sus_list/' . $list->id_list)}}" title="Upload E-mails"><i
                                                    class="material-icons">
                                                    backup
                                                </i></a>
        <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalEdit" href="#" id="linkUpdate" onclick="capturar({{$list->id_list}})"><i
                                                    class="material-icons">edit</i></a>
        <i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
      </td>
    </tr>
    @endforeach
  </tbody>
</table>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalEdit" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelEdit" aria-hidden="true">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <h5 class="modal-title" id="">Create Subscribers List</h5>
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                             <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span>
                         </button>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="POST" action="/sus_list" id="formModalValidate">
          @csrf
          <input type="hidden" name="lista_id" id="idListJs" value="">
          <div class="input-field col s12">
            <label for="list_name" class="col-form-label">List Name:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="list_name" id="recipient-name" minlength="4" required>
          </div>
          <div class="col s12">
            <label for="message-text" class="col-form-label"></label>
            <select name="list_type" id="" class="selectpicker" data-style="btn-white" title="" required>
              <option value="" disabled selected>Type List</option>
              <option value="1">Email Makerting</option>
            </select>
          </div>
          <br>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Update</button>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Si esto resolvió tu problema no olvides marcar tu respuesta como aceptada

Comment: No puedo hacerlo sino hasta después de dos días.

Answer (score 0):

No te recomiendo que hagas un modal por cada registro por que el html recibido podria consumir demasiados datos en el cliente, puedes auxiliarte con JS para hacer un solo modal.

Si aun asi deseas generar un modal por registro, tu error es que todos tienen el mismo id, para solucionarlo debes corregir estos elementos dentro del foreach

```
@foreach ($lists as $key => $list)
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalEdit_{{ $key }}"><i></i></a>
    <!-- Modal -->
      <div class="modal fade" id="exampleModalEdit_{{ $key }}" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabelEdit" aria-hidden="true">
```

Comment: Ahora me rota los id pero no corresponden con el id real, el 35 me lo posiciona en 33